# Codeigniter How to save data from a form to a database

Tags: forms, codeigniter, send

Codeigniter

Hi. I want to send my form data to a database. The data are checked ok but what to do next?

My controlls

```
 <?php

class Form extends CI_Controller {

    function index()
    {
        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));

        $this->load->library('form_validation');

            $this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'Imie', 'required|min_length[5]|max_length[25]|required|alpha'); 
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('surname', 'Nazwisko', 'required|min_length[5]|max_length[25]|required|alpha'); 
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|valid_email'); 
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('number', 'Numer telefonu', 'required|alpha_numeric|max_length[10]'); 
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('brand', 'Marka', 'required|alpha'); 
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('model', 'Model', 'required|alpha'); 
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('year', 'Rok produkcji', 'required|alpha_numeric|max_length[5]'); 
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('km', 'Ilosc KM', 'required|alpha_numeric|max_length[5]'); 
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('licenceseplate', 'Tablica rejestracyjna', 'required|max_length[15]'); 
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('description', 'Opis', 'required|max_length[300]'); 
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('city', 'Miasto', 'required|max_length[30]'); 

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
            $this->load->view('myform');

        }
        else
        {
            $this->load->view('formsuccess');
        }

    }


}
?>
```

My view

```
    <html>
<head>
<title>My Form</title>
</head>
<body>


<?php echo form_open('form'); ?>

<h5>Wpisz swoje imię</h5>
<?php echo form_error('name'); ?>
<input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo set_value('name'); ?>" size="50" />

<h5>Nazwisko</h5>
<?php echo form_error('surname'); ?>
<input type="text" name="surname" value="<?php echo set_value('surname'); ?>" size="50" />

<h5>Email Address</h5>
<?php echo form_error('email'); ?>
<input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo set_value('email'); ?>" size="50" />

<h5>Numer telefonu</h5>
<?php echo form_error('number'); ?>
<input type="text" name="number" value="<?php echo set_value('number'); ?>" size="50" />

<h5>Marka</h5>
<?php echo form_error('brand'); ?>
<input type="text" name="brand" value="<?php echo set_value('brand'); ?>" size="50" />

<h5>Model</h5>
<?php echo form_error('model'); ?>
<input type="text" name="model" value="<?php echo set_value('model'); ?>" size="50" />

<h5>Rok produkcji</h5>
<?php echo form_error('year'); ?>
<input type="text" name="year" value="<?php echo set_value('year'); ?>" size="50" />


<h5>km</h5>
<?php echo form_error('km'); ?>
<input type="text" name="km" value="<?php echo set_value('km'); ?>" size="50" />



<h5>Rejestracja </h5>
<?php echo form_error('licenceseplate'); ?>
<input type="text" name="licenceseplate" value="<?php echo set_value('licenceseplate'); ?>" size="50" />

<h5>Opis </h5>
<?php echo form_error('description'); ?>
<input type="text" name="description" value="<?php echo set_value('description'); ?>" size="50" />

<h5>Miasto </h5>
<?php echo form_error('city'); ?>
<input type="text" name="city" value="<?php echo set_value('city'); ?>" size="50" />



<div><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></div>

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

I don't expect the final solution, but I need help what is the next step

My datebase:

Answer (score 2):

After the form validation you can save data

In your controller

```
    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){
        $this->load->view('myform');
    }
    else {
     $this->your_model->save($data);           
    }
```

your_model.php

```
 public function save($data) {
   $this->db->set($data);
   $this->db->insert(table name here);
   $this->db->insert_id();
 }
```

Comment: You can find all information related to database class on CI 's great great user guide. It is very easy to use. Please excuse my english :)

Answer (score 1):

ok 
My view looks like this:

```
    <?php

class Form extends CI_Controller {

    function index()
    {
        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));

        $this->load->library('form_validation');

            $this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'Imie', 'required|min_length[5]|max_length[25]|required|alpha'); 
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('surname', 'Nazwisko', 'required|min_length[5]|max_length[25]|required|alpha'); 
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|valid_email'); 
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('number', 'Numer telefonu', 'required|alpha_numeric|max_length[10]'); 
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('brand', 'Marka', 'required|alpha'); 
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('model', 'Model', 'required|alpha'); 
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('year', 'Rok produkcji', 'required|alpha_numeric|max_length[5]'); 
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('km', 'Ilosc KM', 'required|alpha_numeric|max_length[5]'); 
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('licenceseplate', 'Tablica rejestracyjna', 'required|max_length[15]'); 
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('description', 'Opis', 'required|max_length[300]'); 
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('city', 'Miasto', 'required|max_length[30]'); 

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
            $this->load->view('myform');

        }
        else
        {
            /*$this->load->view('formsuccess');*/
            $this->load->model ( 'form' );
            $this->form->save($data);
        }

    }


}
?>
```

my model

```
    class form extends Model{

  function form(){
    parent::Model();
    $this->load->helper('url');             
  }

public function save($data) {
   $this->db->set($data);
   $this->db->insert(form);
   $this->db->insert_id();

 }



}
```

table in date base name form

I have no idea how you want it

Answer (score 0):

You have to send the data to the model

There you can use active record or normal query to save the data

It must be noted you need to include the model in the controller

`$this->load->model ( 'Your model name' );` this should be included in the controller

`$this->yourmodelname->functioninmodel` this is the controller function call to the model

Comment: Please give me an example of how it should look like. Kombinował with models already but I can not get the effect